# Which control should be used for a scheduler and how?

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I'm trying to do a scheduler for a lesson schedule. Which control should I use and how to do?

[Here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CB98DD0B6654BA09!115&authkey=!APRIBNGyrtJVFQo&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.png) you find an image of what I'm trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a UserControl based on the "DatePicker" control.

And then redefine the control template, using a UniformGrid.

There is no simple and quick way to do that yourself. Either you recreate a custom control based on a DatePicker, or you try to find a library of controls already doing what you are trying to.
I believe a few controls already exists to do that, but I don't have names to throw in.

Comment: thanks for reply, I'm going to try changing DatePicker control.